# Get the Height of the WPF Expander Header

Tags: wpf, header, height, expander

I need to get the Height of the WPF Expander.Header, not the whole Expander just the Height of the Header.

There is no property to get it because the Expander.Header + Expander.Content is the Expander.Height.

What would you do to get the Expander.Header Height ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your expander isn't templated, that's a Visual tree:

```
Expander { Border { DockPanel { ToggleButton, ContentPresenter {...} } } }
```

All you need is to get that ToggleButton. It's easy using `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(expander, 0);
var dockpanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
var togglebutton = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dockpanel, /*0*/); // it may be not 0th, so please enumerate all children using VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dockpanel) and find that ToggleButton
return togglebutton.ActualHeight;
```

**Edit**

Also, I'd like to accent on using `ActualHeight`, not `Height`, because `Height` is not `double.IsNaN` (in XAML, `auto`) only if set explicitly in code or XAML

Comment: same I found on msdn forum now looks ok :) prolly you found this link too? :P => http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a90b752a-6200-4542-8ec8-29cb902b8aa7

Comment: No, I didn't. Just investigated the visual tree - that's first what I do when some info about element's structure is needed

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to do that exactly (maybe through reflection?), but you could try using two expanders. One with just a header and one with just a ContentPresenter. You could bind the IsExpanded property of the first expander to the IsExpanded property of the second one. This would make them appear to be a single expander.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish though.